# Searching for a one dimensional array in multi dim. array

Tags: arrays, delphi

Please what would be the fastest (and most 'elegant') way to search for *FaDirection* array in the multi dim. *FdVSubs* array?

```
TaDirection = array[0..7] of TSubRect; //TSubRect = class(TObject)

Multi dim array:
FdVSubs: array[0..15] of TaDirection;

Array:
FaDirection : TaDirection;
```

I need to resolve if FaDirection is already stored in FdVSubs or not.

Thank You.

Comment: create a unique ID for each array you add and store in an `Index` array. Much easier to look for it then just looking through one array.

Comment: I think [`this`](http://pastebin.com/wGvPYYXZ) might work.

Comment: Use generics instead if you really need to label and compare often.

Comment: What version of Delphi?  Does TSubRect implement any comparers?  Are you looking to see if `FaDirection` refers to a specific instance of `TaDirection` in `FdVSubs`, or will `FaDirection` be a separate instance that contains an equivalent `TaDirection`?  Same again for `TSubRect` - are you talking about checking for the same instances or equivalency between separate instances?

Comment: @MerlinW. - Good for one, but there are more elegant ways maybe. (:

Comment: @TLama - Thank you, im checking.

Comment: @PeterVonča - I see that everywhere but never used that, (: How would you translate the above to generics? (:

Comment: @J... - 2010, same instances of TSubRect in both array.

Comment: Ok, same instances.  Now, you've asked for two incompatible things - the *fastest* and the *most elegant* way to search.  These will almost always be at extreme opposite ends of the solution spectrum.  Which one do you care most about?  Fastest, or most elegant?  Is this search in a performance bottleneck?

Comment: Also, is the order of `TSubRect`s important?  If `FdVSubs` contains a `TaDirection` that has the same `TSubRect`s as `FaDirection` but in a different order, does it matter?

Comment: @diop078, there's no reason not to use generics today, in this situation you could benefit from using generic TArray<T> since it provides static methods to search and sort an array. Sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: @J... - Then, i vote for elegant, or 'better': the most easy to understand. Speed is not really that important for now. TSubrect instances in FaDirection will be always in the same order as in the FdVSubs (if there is equality).

Comment: @PeterVonča - I will definitely look into that.

Comment: @TLama - Thank you, the function working great, im using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and most important, you need to decide what defines two arrays as being equal. Then you'll have to adjust my code to match that definition. For the answer I'll assume arrays are equal if and only if they have identical object references at each corresponding position in the arrays.

```
function DirectionsAreEqual(const ADirection1, ADirection2: TaDirection): Boolean;
var
  LoopI: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for LoopI := Low(TaDirection) to High(TaDirection) do
  begin
    if (ADirection1[LoopI] <> ADirection2[LoopI]) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function DirectionExistsIn(const ADirection: TaDirection;
    const ADirectionList: array of TaDirection): Boolean;
var
  LoopI: Integer;
begin
  Result := False; //Caters for empty DirectionList
  for LoopI := Low(ADirectionList) to High(ADirectionList) do
  begin
    Result := DirectionsAreEqual(ADirection, ADirectionList[LoopI]);
    if (Result) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

//Then you can simply do the test as follows:
if DirectionExistsIn(FaDirection, FdVSubs) then ...
```

**NOTES**

- DirectionExistsIn uses an Open Array, so it doesn't matter how many elements are defined for the FdVSubs array.
- A small change to DirectionExistsIn can allow you to return the position of the duplicate.

Comment: Yes but i thought maybe it can be done with fewer lines of code. Something like TLamas solution (can try that only tomorrow), or well, i dont know. (:

Comment: @diop078 TLama's code should work. However it does rely on memory tricks; albeit tricks that are pretty well entrenched and unlikely to be affected by changes to Delphi. However, those tricks do raise the bar in terms of understanding the code. Even though the code is shorter, if it gives you pause to think... is it really better?

Comment: @diop078 PS: Just to add, there are still many more ways you can approach this. (as many as to skin a cat)... E.g. Currently TaDirection is an array. What if instead you make it a class? Then you will gain the ability to empower TaDirection object instances with methods allow you to very concisely query all sorts of information and perform any number of rich operations.

Comment: @Craig, I doubt there will be change in how `CompareMem` works. I got the question as OP wants to loop an array and check if inside this array is an array of pointers (`array of TObject` actually) which equals to the input array of pointers (`array of TObject` actually). If the OP doesn't need a deep comparision of those objects (which mine nor yours code doesn't), I believe `CompareMem` could be the shortest (and still understandable) way. Besides, you can comment such line of code to keep understanding of what's going on. Yours code is better prepared for deep comparision of objects though.